# Most performant way to bulk insert in MongoDB

Tags: performance, mongodb, performance-testing, bulkinsert, database-performance

There are two ways to bulk insert documents in MongoDB:

1. Passing in an array of documents to [`db.collection.insert`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/#insert-multiple-documents), or
2. Use [`Bulk.insert`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk.insert/) - available as of v2.6

Which one is more performant? I am assuming the latter is used as a convenience when combined with other write operations in a single block of  Bulk Write Operations, and so the first is more performant. But has anyone done any tests or have logical or empirical proof on this?

Comment: I mostly do updates and deletes in bulk and haven't done any accurate testing, but in my experience the bulk operations are faster. They also appear to place less load on the server

Answer (score 5):

At the mongo shell prompt, type

```
db.test.insert
```

You'll see the code for this function. If you read it, you'll see that passing in an array to `insert` and doing a bulk insert are the same thing. You need to look at the whole code, which is too lengthy to post here, to understand exactly what happens, but the key part is

```
var isMultiInsert = Array.isArray(obj);

if (isMultiInsert) {
    obj.forEach(function(doc) {
        bulk.insert(doc);
    });
}
else {
    bulk.insert(obj);
}

try {
    result = bulk.execute(wc);
    if (!isMultiInsert)
        result = result.toSingleResult();
}
```

This code is from the 2.6.7 mongo shell.